# Centos 6.2 mysql configuration file help

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have a new centos 6.2 setup. Below is the configuration file. The machine is going to be fully innodb and it had 8Gb ram. What else must I include in the .cnf?

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using ? Did you load all the data into the database already?

Comment: I am using the version which comes with centos  6.2 that is 5.1. No is a brand  new server we do not know how much full load data yet. So what settings is best here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should configure is the innoDB buffer pool size. According to [this blog entry](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/) by Percona, the ideal buffer pool size is 10% larger than your total data size.

Other settings to add: InnoDB log file size, query cache size.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12G

query_cache_size=500M

innodb_log_file_size=64M
```

Comment: I have read the blog but how do we decide the total data size is it based on the ibdata files size. I have set it to be per table basis. My server only have 8Gb ram so how it relates to 12G I am kind of confuse here.